# more efficient way to count number of objects in a list

Tags: java, eclipse

I need help! I am a beginner, but is there a more efficient way to count the number of objects in the list and returns the total??

```
 public int size() {

    int length = 0;

    // For each loop that can enumerate the list and counts the elements. 
    for( Object o : this ) {
        length++;
    }

    return length;
}
```

Comment: there is no list in your example.  all java containers have a size() method that returns the value you want...very fast

Comment: What is `this`? Wheres your list?

Comment: maybe the OP's class is implementing `List` and needs to overwrite it? If not visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: There's very likely a more efficient way to get the size. But we can't help you without more context.

Comment: Scary Wombat you are probably correct, but this shows that the problem is not well understood.  assuming that the OP has other code that is the list, then i think we are safe to suggest that he keep a length variable that gets updated every time an element is added.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with arrays, you can use array.length property to get the number of elements. If you are using a `List`, just call the method `size()` in the object. Example:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3};
arr.length; //3
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
list.size(); //3
```

Answer (score 0):

You always have `size` method on `arrayList`, but you could implement your own. Check this:

### MainProgram:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ObjectNum
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        List < String > stringList = new ArrayList < String > ( );
        stringList.add ( "FirstElement" );
        stringList.add ( "secondLement" );
        List < Integer > intList = new ArrayList < Integer > ( );
        intList.add ( 1 );
        intList.add ( 2 );
        intList.add ( 3 );
        //Using default methods
        System.out.println ( "Default size stringList: " + stringList.size ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "Default size intList: " + intList.size ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "Custom size stringList: " +countElements ( stringList ) );
        System.out.println ( "Custom size intList: " + countElements ( intList ) );

    }

    public static <E> int countElements ( List < E > list)
    {
        int size = 0;
        for( Object o : list)
        {
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }

}
```

### Output:

```
Default size stringList: 2
Default size intList: 3
Custom size stringList: 2
Custom size intList: 3
```